# FluorineFx Inspect AMF Header

Tags: amf, fluorinefx

Currently, using Flex using FluorineFx to connect .Net back end.  On the flex side I am injecting a custom value into the AMF3 header.  Does anyone know how to get to the AMF header on the .Net side after FluorineFx has parsed the request?  It is not apparent to me if FluorineFx gives me access to the AMF3 message after it has parsed it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```cs
var amfMessage =
    (AmfBaseMessage) OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage;
var header = amfMessage.AmfHeaders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "HeaderName");
var headerValue = header.Content as string;
```

Just replace `HeaderName` and `as string` as the appropriate name and type for your needs.